# How to pass a List<Child> to a method with parameter List<Parent>?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, generics, inheritance

I've been away from inheritance for a while and need a little helping hand.

I have an abstract base class `Chief`. There are two inheriting classes `Ship` and `Vehicle`, which share several properties via `Chief`.

I have a method which uses those common properties:

```
public static void AssignRandomProperties(PSetList routeSettings, List<Chief> theChiefs)
```

but when I try to pass a

```
List<Ship>
```

or a

```
List<Vehicle>
```

I'm told that they can't be converted. Here's a sample method call:

```
ChiefRouteRandomizer.AssignRandomProperties(s.Route, theVehicles);
```

I was assuming of course that the `List<Vehicle>` would be treated as a `List<Chief>` when passed as the argument to `AssignRandomProperties`, but apparently not. Does the list need converting to `List<Chief>` first? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I cast a List<T> effectively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504729/how-do-i-cast-a-listt-effectively)

Comment: @Gabe: The answer to that question is completely inappropriate for this question.  The two questions have a very different context.

Comment: cdhowie: The answer to that question is `.Cast<>.ToList()` and your answer of `.ToList<>()` is equivalent (but better). Although your second suggestion doesn't directly follow from that question (the OP doesn't give as much context), it's certainly applicable to both questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First some explanation.  You cannot convert `List<Vehicle>` to `List<Chief>` because then the Add method would have the signature `void List<Chief>.Add(Chief item)` and you would be able to store instances of the `Chief` class in a list that was declared to only hold `Vehicle`s.  This would break the type system; therefore it is not allowed.

The easiest way to get around this is to pass in `theVehicles.ToList<Chief>()`.  However, this will create a new list.  This has two implications: (1) You would be wasting memory by duplicating the list, and (2) if the method is going to mutate the list itself (add/remove items or replace members with other members) you will not see those changes on the `theVehicles` list.  (If the objects the references in the list point to are the only things being modified, this is not a problem.)

If you have control over the AssignRandomProperties method, consider using this signature instead:

```
public static void AssignRandomProperties<T>(
    PSetList routeSettings,
    IList<T> theChiefs) where T : Chief
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very very much for the clear explanation and generic method code. That's exactly the 'breakthrough' I was looking for. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```
List<Ship> ships = new List<Ship>();
List<Chief> asChiefs = (List<Chief>)ships;
asChiefs.Add(new Car());
// so what, now ships[0] is a Car?
```

That's why you cannot treat a list of ships as a list of chiefs. If you want to learn more about this, it is said that List is not [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) (and neither is it contravariant).

Now, does your AssignRandomProperties method really need to take a `List<T>`? If all you do is iterate it, you don't need a `List<T>`, you can do fine with an `IEnumerable<T>`, which `List<T>` implements. The good thing here is `IEnumerable<T>` provides no methods for modification of the list, so it is covariant (starting with .NET 4). This means you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<Chief> chiefs = ships;
```

Comment: FYI, `IEnumerable<T>` is only covariant in .NET 4.  Pre-4 code will require `IEnumerable<Chief> chiefs = ships.Cast<Chief>();`, which is of course still better than duplicating the list.

Comment: Since the title begins with "c# 4: " I guess I can assume that.

Comment: Yeah, I was not directing that comment at you so much as others who might be reading and not know that this is a 4.0-specific feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my favorite trick

```
public static void AssignRandomProperties<T>(PSetList routeSettings, List<T> theChiefs) 
    where T : Chief
```

Then, you call like following

```
AssignRandomProperties<Vehicle>(s.Route, theVehicles);
```

Comment: `<Vehicle>` is unnecessary; the compiler will infer the generic arguments by the types of the standard arguments.

Comment: @cdhowie Oh, thanks.  I didn't know that. Then, the code is even cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the that. That's what I'm using as per Howie's reply.

Comment: The methodName<T> (list<T> list) is what I needed for my solution -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your method body looks like this:

```
public static void AssignRandomProperties(PSetList routeSettings, List<Chief> theChiefs)
{
    foreach (var chief in theChiefs)
    {
        //assign some properties
    }
}
```

and assuming that you are using C# 4.0, which introduced covariance and contravariance, you could do this, avoiding the generic solutions already suggested:

```
public static void AssignRandomProperties(PSetList routeSettings, IEnumerable<Chief> theChiefs)
{
    foreach (var chief in theChiefs)
    {
        //assign some properties
    }
}
```