# Verify the type of custom class in function

Tags: c#, type-conversion

In C#,I have a public function that can pass a List parameter, with T is a custom class. The function can pass with different T class. The problem that how to verify the type of T in every case?

```
public static List<T> ConvertData(List<T> oldDatas)
{
  //I will analyze the object T, 
  //but now i don't know how to verify the type of T, 
  //with T  can change,
  //example maybe T is T1 class,or T2 class..
}
```

Thanks for my stupid question.

Comment: Which language ? `C#`, `Java`? Tag the question with correct programming language you are using.

Answer (score 2):

this is for C#

```
Type gt = typeof(T);
```

check this for java : [Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to make different converting depends on  or just want to check  for specific classes? In second case you can try to specify right types for T something like:

```
public static List<string> ConvertData(List<string> data)
{
    return PrivateConvertData<string>(data);
}

public static List<int> ConvertData(List<int> data)
{
    return PrivateConvertData<int>(data);
}

private static List<T> PrivateConvertData<T>(List<T> data)
{
    // code here
}
```

This code will check type of T during compilation.

Comment: Because T is a sql to Linq class, so that it have some properties in every T object. How can I get propeties?

Comment: Do you need the same properties from different classes or your properties list depends on your class?

Answer (score 2):

just do :

```
public static class Test<T> 
    where T : class, new()
{
    public static List<T> ConvertData(List<T> oldDatas)
    {
        T instanceOfT = new T();
        Type typeOfT = typeof(T); // or instanceOfT.GetType();

        if(instanceOfT is string)
        {
            // T is a string
        }
        else if(instanceOfT is int)
        {
            // T is an int
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

But that isn't productive and break the generic concept... Explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `typeof(T)` keyword or use some check (if you are expecting some types to be passed via parameters):

```
 public static List<T> ConvertData(List<T> oldDatas)
 {
     foreach (var itemList in oldDatas)
     {
         if (itemList is LinqType)
         {
             var linqTypeItem = (LinqType) itemList;
             Console.WriteLine(linqTypeItem.PROPERTY_YOU_NEED);
         }
         // or
         var linqTypeItem = itemList as LinqType;
         if (linqTypeItem != null)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(linqTypeItem.PROPERTY_YOU_NEED);
         }
     }
 }
```

Also you can use the `Cast()` method. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504729/how-do-i-cast-a-listt-effectively)

Comment: In here, T is a object of Linq. So that how can I get the property of object.