# Issues with the "where" in generic inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, casting

in the following code is an problem on line `entities = doSpecialStuff(entities);` because i'm "missing" something in where part from my `doSpecialStuff()` Methode

**`Error`**
`The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

    'myWorkClass<T>.doSpecialStuff<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)'. There is no implicit 
    reference conversion from 'T' to 'ISpezial'.)`

### Code

here are my ineritance structure

```
public class Baseclass { }

public interface ISpezial 
{ 
    int mySpecial{get;set;} 
}

public class Class1 : Baseclass { }

public class Class2 : Baseclass, ISpezial
{
    public int mySpecial{ get;set;}
}
```

here is my data provider

```
public class myRepository
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Load<TResult>() where TResult : Baseclass, new()
    {
        List<TResult> myEnum = new List<TResult>();

        if (typeof(ISpezial).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TResult)))
        {
            myEnum.Add((new Class2() { mySpecial = 0 }) as TResult);
            myEnum.Add((new Class2() { mySpecial = 1 }) as TResult);
            myEnum.Add((new Class2() { mySpecial = 2 }) as TResult);
        }
        else
        {
            myEnum.Add((new Class1() as TResult));
            myEnum.Add((new Class1() as TResult));
            myEnum.Add((new Class1() as TResult));
        }

        return myEnum;
    }
}
```

and there it is the class who does stuff and provides errors like a boss

```
public class myWorkClass<T> where T : Baseclass, new()
{
    public void doNormalStuff()
    {
        var entities = myRepository.Load<T>();
        if (typeof(ISpezial).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            entities = doSpecialStuff(entities);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> doSpecialStuff<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) where T : ISpezial
    {
        var list = new List<T>();

        return list.Where(special => special.mySpecial==2);
    }
}
```

### some further question

How can i avoid the `new()` in my where's?

and how can i change the Add part `myRepository` to do `myEnum.Add(new Class1());` instead of `myEnum.Add((new Class1() as TResult));` without changing the return `IEnumerable<TResult>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no implicit conversion between T (Baseclass or child of Baseclass), it's not enough to check if ISpezial is assignable (which you do, and it's very good like that), you also need to **explicitly** cast the variable when passing it as a parameter, and then cast it back. It's really not the best class design, though.

```
 entities = doSpecialStuff(entities.Cast<ISpezial>()).Cast<T>();
```

2nd question: since you explicitly call Class2() and Class1() constructors, you're not really relying on the polymorphism/generic typing of C#, which is why the new() constraint is there (if you wrote new T(), for example). So as long as you keep your code like that, you can remove the constraint.

3rd: you can make use of the *dynamics* keyword, make your list of dynamic type, and cast only in the last moment:

```
List<dynamic> myEnum = new List<dynamic>();
//your code
myEnum.Add((new Class2() { mySpecial = 0 })); //it's ok to write like you want it now
//your code
return myEnum.Cast<TResult>();
```

Comment: Not at all - unless you are working with literally millions of objects, case in which you'll lose a fraction of a second.

Edit(wrong link before): see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504729/how-do-i-cast-a-listt-effectively

Comment: ok after testing a bit with 10,000,000  objects  agree with you :D

Comment: +1 for being pragmatic and actually testing it. Keep it up :D